# Retrofit reciving API Data but List is empty

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I'm trying to receive user data from an API for a personal project. but whenever i try to access the List of Data it's empty.

I would try to call something like this(users.values.get(0).name) inside of the ViewModel and my app will keep crashing. giving me a null pointer exeception

PurpleTeapotDatingApiService.kt

```
package com.example.purpleteapotdating.API

import com.example.redteapotdating.models.Users
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET

private const val BASE_URL = "https://w1yeg.wiremockapi.cloud"

/**
 * Building a Moshi object with a Kotlin adapter factory that retrofit will be using
 */

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()


/**
 * Building the retrofit object with the moshi converter
 */

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()



interface PurpleTeapotDatingApiService {
    @GET("users")
    suspend fun getUsers(): List<Users>
}

object PurpleTeapotDatingAPI{
    val retrofitService: PurpleTeapotDatingApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(PurpleTeapotDatingApiService::class.java) }
}
```

Users model

```
data class Users (
    @Json(name = "id")val id: Int,
    @Json(name = "name")val name: String,
    @Json(name = "photo")val photo: String?,
    @Json(name = "gender")val gender: String?,
    @Json(name = "about")val about: String?,
    @Json(name = "school")val school: String?,
    @Json(name = "hobbies") val hobbies: List<String>?
)
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.purpleteapotdating.view

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import com.example.purpleteapotdating.R

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {


    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //Retrieve the navController from the NavHost Fragment
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        //Set up the action bar for use with the NavController
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    }

    /**
     * Handles the navigation when the user chooses back from the action bar
     */
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

PurpleTeapotDatingFragment.kt

```
package com.example.purpleteapotdating.view

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import com.example.purpleteapotdating.databinding.FragmentDatingBinding
import com.example.purpleteapotdating.viewmodel.PurpleTeapotDatingViewModel
import com.example.redteapotdating.models.Users

class PurpleTeapotDatingFragment: Fragment() {
    
    private var binding: FragmentDatingBinding? = null
    private val viewModel: PurpleTeapotDatingViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private lateinit var usersList: List<Users>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val fragmentBinding = FragmentDatingBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        binding = fragmentBinding
        return fragmentBinding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding?.viewModel = viewModel
        binding?.datingFragment = this
        binding?.lifecycleOwner = this
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding = null
    }
}
```

PurpleTeapotDatingViewModel

```
package com.example.purpleteapotdating.viewmodel

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.purpleteapotdating.API.PurpleTeapotDatingAPI
import com.example.redteapotdating.models.Users
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class PurpleTeapotDatingViewModel: ViewModel() {

    //internal mutable data
    private val _users = MutableLiveData<List<Users>>()

    //external immutable data
    val users: LiveData<List<Users>> = _users

    init {
        getUsers()
    }

    private fun getUsers()
    {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            Log.v("getUsers()", "Loading...")
            try {
                _users.value = PurpleTeapotDatingAPI.retrofitService.getUsers()
                Log.v("getUsers()", "Success!!")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("getUsers()","Failure: ${e.message}")
                _users.value = listOf()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_dating.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.purpleteapotdating.viewmodel.PurpleTeapotDatingViewModel" />
        <variable
            name="datingFragment"
            type="com.example.purpleteapotdating.view.PurpleTeapotDatingFragment" />
    </data>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline3"
                android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_emphasis_medium"
                tools:text="Jim"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id = "@+id/genderLayout"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/gender"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline4"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_emphasis_medium"
                    tools:text="Gender" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/genderIdentity"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_emphasis_medium"
                    tools:text="Male" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/aboutLayout">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/about"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline4"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_emphasis_medium"
                    tools:text="About" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/AboutMe"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_emphasis_medium"
                    tools:text="i like turtelz :)" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/schoolLayout"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/school"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline4"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_emphasis_medium"
                    tools:text="School" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id = "@+id/schoolName"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    tools:text="John Jay college"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_emphasis_medium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/hobbiesLayout">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/hobbies"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline4"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_emphasis_medium"
                    tools:text="Hobbies" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/hobbiesList"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_emphasis_medium" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                tools:text="next">
            </Button>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your method in `PurpleTeapotDatingApiService` return `Call<List<Users>>`

So it will look like this :

```
interface PurpleTeapotDatingApiService {
    @GET("users")
    suspend fun getUsers(): Call<List<Users>>
}
```

Then use the `enqueue` method to debug your API call

```
PurpleTeapotDatingApiService.getUsers().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Users>> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Users>>, response: Response<List<Users>>) {
                    
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Users>>, t: Throwable) {

                }

            })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not get Livedata like that. Because queries that return LiveData, are working asynchronously. The value is null at that moment when you call `users.values.get(0).name` inside viewmodel.
You need to observe that live data inside PurpleTeapotDatingFragment.

```
        private val viewModel: PurpleTeapotDatingViewModel by viewModels()

        viewModel.users.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { usersData ->
            // Now you can get the data
            // usersData.get(0).name
        }
```